# Почему убрали ::std::is_pod?

Tags: c++, pod, c++20

Почему в С++20 задепрекейтили `::std::is_pod`? Как теперь узнать, что тип является POD?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225673/why-is-stdis-pod-deprecated-in-c20
вот тут все подробно описано

Comment: @Zhihar https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55974373#55974373

Comment: это просто английская версия

Answer (score 2):

POD заменяется двумя категориями, которые дают больше нюансов. На [стандартном собрании c ++ в ноябре 2017 г.] [1](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2017/11/20/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-albuquerque-november-2017/) об этом говорилось следующее:

> Отказ от понятия «старые простые данные» (POD). Он был заменен на две более тонкие категории типов: «тривиальный» и «стандартный макет». «POD» эквивалентен «тривиальному и стандартному макету», но для многих шаблонов кода уместно более узкое ограничение до «тривиального» или просто «стандартного макета»; Поэтому для поощрения такой точности понятие «POD» было объявлено устаревшим. Библиотечный трейт is_pod также устарел.

Для простых типов данных используйте функцию [ʻis_standard_layout`] [2], для тривиальных типов данных (таких как простые структуры) используйте функцию [ʻis_trivial`] [3](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial).

Answer (score 0):

POD is being replaced with two categories that give more nuances. The [c++ standard meeting in november 2017](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2017/11/20/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-albuquerque-november-2017/) had this to say about it:

> Deprecating the notion of “plain old data” (POD). It has been replaced with two more nuanced categories of types, “trivial” and “standard-layout”. “POD” is equivalent to “trivial and standard layout”, but for many code patterns, a narrower restriction to just “trivial” or just “standard layout” is appropriate; to encourage such precision, the notion of “POD” was therefore deprecated. The library trait is_pod has also been deprecated correspondingly.

For simple data types use the [`is_standard_layout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout) function, for trivial data types (such as simple structs) use the [`is_trivial`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial) function.

Comment: может хотя бы перевести?